# Gulp: Segmentation Fault 11 after Node 4.0 update

Tags: node.js, gulp, fault

I just updated to Node 4.

When I run Gulp, I see:

> Segmentation fault: 11

My includes:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var jscs = require('gulp-jscs');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var responsive = require('gulp-responsive');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var jpegtran = require('imagemin-jpegtran');
var rollup = require('gulp-rollup');
var webp = require('gulp-webp');
var spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith');
```

I am unable to get a debug task to run. Verbose doesn't spit out anything additional.

Thoughts?

Comment: Remove your `node_modules` directory, then run `npm cache clean && npm install`. Lastly `npm uninstall -g gulp && npm install -g gulp`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I also update to Node 4.0 and get a segmentation fault on my node server too. I just delete my node_modules directory and rerun `npm install`, and it is fine.

So I suspect it is because the new version of npm has trouble to load some modules installed by old npm --- but just for some modules, it is OK to directly run `npm start` after updating on my other servers. I haven't went deep into this.

As a quick fix I think you can try this on your own dependencies.

Answer (score 11):

The suggestion to delete `node_modules` and then run `npm install` is a good one. It will work. Slightly more efficient, though, might be to just run `npm rebuild` without deleting `node_modules` or running `npm install`. It will re-compile native modules for the new version of Node/V8 you have installed without having to download all the files again.

But if all else fails:

- Remove your node_modules directory
- `npm cache clean && npm install`
- `npm uninstall -g gulp && npm install -g gulp`

Comment: The `npm rebuild` step didn't solve the problem for me. Your other suggestion is a duplicate of previous suggestions.

Comment: Upvoted you @Trott because, although it partially duplicated others, it was a very thorough answer with possible alternatives. +1 from me.

Comment: Aw, thanks. At the risk of sounding peevish, the whole having a problem with duplicating another answer is a little misguided anyway. The answer I'm supposedly duplicating happens to actually duplicate [the comment I had already made on the original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470067/gulp-segmentation-fault-11-after-node-4-0-update/32488684?noredirect=1#comment52802572_32470067). And that's totally fine, whether it was intentional or not. The point is to craft the most useful answer, not to be fastest or most original.

Comment: This worked for me! I was getting a segmentation fault [1] with laravel-elixir tried lots of other things but this worked. Thanks @Trott

Comment: I only had to run npm cache clean and it fixed my issue

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue recently, and attempted the steps shown above:

```
$ npm cache clean && npm install
```

But was still getting the fault. Even after deleting all files and running

```
$ npm install
```

So, did some more rooting, and found that there was an issue whereby some of the node modules had a files ending in .info, which caused Drupal (in which I'm running this framework) to attempt reading the .info files as the theme.info file. Renaming these files (with a different ending) fixed the issue.

Although my problem Drupal-specific, I could imagine similar issues cropping up on other frameworks, as well.

Answer (score 1):

My case the problem was that I had Node v5.9.0 installed. So I downgraded to v4.4.1-LTS and finally got it working again:

Using Homebrew:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/versions
$ brew install homebrew/versions/node4-lts
```

And then:

```
$ npm rebuild
```

Answer (score 1):

I run across this bug today again. After about a hour of searching, reinstalling whole node.js, all plugins and gulp and cleaning cache of NPM, without solving it. I tried to go back few steppes in my SASS file.

And fixed it. But it was not by some mistake or variable in code but I made this statement to my file:

```
a
   transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out

   &:hover, &:focus
       transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
```

Tried to make it again and again that bug occured. Really do not know why. When I use this statement nested in a class or another tag, it is working properly.

Comment: You might want to file an issue bug with node-sass on Gitub if that's your processor.

Comment: Fixed the issue by upgrading the gulp-sass dependency to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

Please, delete your node_modules from project and do `npm install`